# Select and delete entries from database in one go

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query that `SELECT`s some entries based on a certain filter, and then `DELETE`s them.

This would normally be as easy as `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE foo = bar; DELETE * FROM sometable WHERE foo = bar;`. However, I am dealing with a very, very large table, and so am very concerned with performance issues. Hence, I want to go over a table *only once*, and for every row selected, delete that row as well (the above query goes over the table *twice*: once for `SELECT`, and once more for `DELETE`).

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to `Select` everything that will be deleted before you run the `Delete` command, it will have to be two statements.  Do you have a need for the `Select` statement?  If not, you could just run the `Delete` statement.

Comment: @Siyual - yes, I need the rows to be selected as well. So, it isn't possible?

Comment: You could make a `Trigger on Delete` that `Select`s the deleted records as you delete them.

Comment: @Siyual how would I do that?

Comment: The performance of `select` + `delete` will depend a lot on the table schema, indexes, etc. You shouldn't start out assuming that it will be twice as slow (for example) than just `delete` or whatever magic you're hoping to find. This magic probably doesn't exist, but your perceived performance problem might not exist either, or might be far different from what you expect.

Comment: @grossvogel Considering the size of my table (billions of entries), the performance problem most certainly *does* exist. However, I'm not sure if `DELETE` is as slow as `SELECT` is (which is pretty slow on my table).

Comment: @Bluefire: What I'm getting at is this: If you have indexes that need to be rewritten, `delete` could be much much slower than `select`. It could be so slow that the extra `select` pales in comparison. I can't say that's the case, of course. I'm just saying you need to fully understand the performance issue before trying to solve it.

Comment: @grossvogel When you say "could be", do you mean "I think it is", or "I'm not sure but it might as well be"?

Comment: @Bluefire: I'm sorry, and I'm not trying to antagonize you. Of course I'm not sure. I'm just suggesting that you do some testing to better understand the performance issue before focusing too closely on the extra select operation, because it may not be the actual culprit. In my experience, inserts and deletes often perform worse than reads and are more likely to block other db operations as well.

Comment: @grossvogel I wasn't angry :o sorry if it came across that way. I was genuinely wondering if you were asserting that `DELETE`s are slower than selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with a very large table, I suggest you to retrieve the rows by chunks (use limit) and order by a primary key, and then run the delete by using the primary key in "in clause"

this way u will not lock your others and slow down your server while u are deleting the rows.

run those in a loop in your code while u get

```
SELECT * FROM sometable 
    WHERE foo = bar 
    AND  your_primary_key > last_checked_value 
    ORDER BY your_primary_key  limit 100; 


DELETE from sometable 
    WHERE  your_primary_key 
    IN (value1,value2,...,...,value100);
```